# apache Netbeans 12.5 couldn't find or load main class

Tags: netbeans, ant

Mi problema es que usando apache netbeans, compilaba perfectamente de manera normal, hasta que derrepente he necesitado desactivar la opción compile on save para que compile, sin más y sin haber tocado nada. He probado clean and build, reiniciar el pc, cambiar el JDK, reinstalar el IDE entre otras cosas. La cosa es que con esa opción desactivada funciona... pero salen líneas arriba bastante molestas y tarda mas en compilar, adjunto las líneas de arriba, con un hola mundo de ejemplo.

[image: lineasIncomodas]

A continuación adjunto el error si marco la opción compile on save:

[image: errorCompileOnSave]

El código no lo adjunto porque es un simple hola mundo para demostrar el error. Como he dicho ha sido derrepente y llevo meses compilando cosas más complejas.